# malloc struct pointer throwing segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have these two structs

```
struct node{
    int val;
    struct node *up;
    struct node *down;
};

struct stack {
    struct node *bottom;
};
```

The typedef struct is defined in a header file

```
typedef struct stack stack_set;
```

I am trying to `malloc` the structs but I keep getting seg faults when I try to access the `node` struct. I have tried using `malloc` on the `node` struct to no avail.

```
    stack_set *set;
    set = malloc(sizeof(stack_set));
    set->bottom = NULL;
    set = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    set->bottom->val = NULL;
    return set;
```

I hit a seg fault on the second last line of code.

How do I properly `malloc` my code so I don't keep throwing seg faults?
I haven't been able to find an example that could aid in resolving mine.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like misptint in fourth line (also you mix `root` and `bottom`). Try this:

```
stack_set *set;
set = malloc(sizeof(stack_set));
set->bottom = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
set->bottom->val = 0;     // it is better to initialize
set->bottom->up = NULL;   // all fields to avoid undefined
set->bottom->down = NULL; // behaviour in the future
return set;
```

Also it is better to check result of memory allocation functions:

```
stack_set *set;
set = malloc(sizeof(stack_set));
if (!set)
  return NULL;
set->bottom = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if (!set->bottom) {
  free(set);
  return NULL;
}
set->bottom->val = 0;
set->bottom->up = NULL;
set->bottom->down = NULL;
return set;
```

Comment: Wow, thankyou, it works now :D I'll definitely utilise this thorough checking method as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The standard [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) function.  is returning *uninitialized* memory. You need to initialize it. So after

```
    set = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

all of your `set` fields contain *garbage* values (or `malloc` failed and gave `NULL`). In particular you should not dereference `set->root`, this is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and might seems to work if unlucky.

I would recommend using `calloc`to get zeroed memory:

```
   set = calloc(1, sizeof(struct stack));
   if (!set) {perror("calloc stack"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   set->bottom = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
   if (!set->bottom) {perror("calloc node"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

If you can't use `calloc` clear the memory using `memset`.

Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer and the tips on using calloc. I will try use valgrind as well.